# Kafka Stream StateStore infinite loop

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a KStream app that uses in-memory KV StateStore but with changelog disabled.

```
  String stateStoreName = "statestore-v1";
  StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Event>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
      Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(stateStoreName), 
          Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(Event.class));
  keyValueStoreBuilder.withLoggingDisabled();
  streamsBuilder.addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder);
```

We now want to enable the changelog with different configuration and different name.

```
  String stateStoreName = "statestore-v2";
  StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Event>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
      Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(stateStoreName), 
          Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(Event.class));
  Map<String, String> changelogConfig = new HashMap<>();
  changelogConfig.put("retention.ms", "43200000"); // 12 hours
  changelogConfig.put("cleanup.policy", "delete");
  changelogConfig.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
  keyValueStoreBuilder.withLoggingEnabled(changelogConfig);
  streamsBuilder.addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder);
```

When we run our application, we got into infinite loop with these messages:

```
2022-10-11 13:02:32.761 app=myapp INFO 54561 --- [-StreamThread-3]
o.a.k.s.p.i.StoreChangelogReader : stream-thread [myapp-StreamThread-3] 
End offset for changelog myapp-statestore-v2-changelog-4 cannot be found; 
will retry in the next time.
2022-10-11 13:02:32.761 app=myapp INFO 54561 --- [-StreamThread-3] 
o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=myapp-StreamThread-3-restore-consumer, groupId=null] 
Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
```

It does not appear that the changelog topic is ever created... At least `kafka-topics` does not show it.

I am using io.confluent packages version 7.2.2-ccs, which I think translates to Apache Kafka version 3.2.x

Any ideas on how to fix the infinite loop and get the changelog topics created?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to reset your app (`kafka-streams-application-reset` command) if you modify the topology or its properties

Comment: If we use `kafka-streams-application-reset` wouldn't my app starts processing the input topic from scratch (or whatever offset we reset it to)? We don't want to disturb the processing of the input topic. I.e: we don't want to reprocess from start or skip anything. We just want to enable the StateStore changelog internal topic.

Comment: Correct. And I dont think you can do that without changing the topology of the job. In other words, your changelog topic must be created from the beginning of the original consumed topic to process all key-value pairs

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop was caused because we were doing Blue/Green deployment. We learned that we can not do this if we are changing anything with the StateStore (configuration or disabling/re-enabling changelogs).

We just did a complete shutdown of the old version, then deployed the new version. That worked fine.

Another option would be to use the `kafka-streams-application-reset` tool as OneKricketeer suggested.